# Use Exchange webmail with a full mail client

Tags: email, exchange, webmail

My university uses exchange. Unfortuantly, they block the Exchange ports, so the only way to use the university email from a non-campus PC is to use webmail. The webmail is very basic unless you use IE. I need a way to access my Exchange mail with a full email client like Thunderbird.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Davmail](http://davmail.sourceforge.net/) acts as a gateway between Outlook Web Access (OWA) and a standard mail client by using local servers. There is calendar and GAL support too.